# Why is my exterior PVC water main covered in vinyl wrap?

Tags: plumbing, code-compliance, pvc

[image]I'm going to replace the main water shutoff valve that feeds my house. The 1" PVC water line comes up thru the ground and then threads into 1" copper (that's the part I'm going to alter). I may have to cut off some of that 1" PVC and reglue a threaded connector

What is confusing me is that there is 10mil Calpico vinyl tape wrapped around the 10 inches that come out of the ground. Is this normal? Is it required by code? Is it there to protect the PVC from UV damage?

PICTURE SHOWS WATER MAIN RISING ON RIGHT GOING INTO OLD COPPER VALVE I PLAN TO REPLACE

Comment: Pvc threaded? Are you sure it’s not a metallic pipe with a pvc coating? It sounds like protection from dielectric currents but that’s just a guess, any photos?

Comment: its definitely PVC. i can see the white threaded end where it connects to the old copper valve that I plan to replace

Comment: How about a photo, I don’t remember ever seeing threaded pvc pipe unless it is a glued on threaded connector. Trying to not tell you a wrong thing to do.

Comment: ...and now you can do some cleanup by deleting comments that are obsolete (as I just did, and will again shortly.) *i.e.* you got the pictures in, so those ones can go...

Comment: no body likes the cleanup. ok no problem

Answer (score 2):

Plumbing PVC is damaged by UV / Sunlight, and needs some sort of protection where exposed. Electrical PVC has UV resistance, but is not rated for plumbing uses.

*Schedule 80 PVC is quite commonly threaded. Schedule 40 is not, in my experience (IME.) Schedule 40 only uses glued-on pipe thread adapters, IME*

Comment: I have seen many sch 40 threaded installs but on irrigation system. im pretty sure my water main shown is sch 40 , i think sch 80 is grey in color?.   your answer makes sense that its wrapped to protect from UV and not because its going into the dirt.